# Como deixar uma div torta?

Tags: css3

Olá, recentemente achei um layout no Google e achei a ideia dele bem interessante, mas não sei como reproduzir a div daquela maneira, é basicamente fazer com que a div fique 'torta', tentei reproduzir mas quando eu utilizava o rotate(), a div entortava mas não ficava colada nas duas laterais, mesmo com width: 100%; então irei postar o layout aqui e agradeceria se alguém me mostrasse como realizar a mesma coisa em uma daquelas divs.  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Duplicata de [Layout com div em diagonal e responsivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75691/3635).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie 2 divs, uma que será o container da outra:

```
<div class="skew">
    <div>Texto</div>
</div>
```

e defina o estilo da primeira com o transform de `skewY` desejado:

```
-ms-transform: skewY(-12deg);
-webkit-transform: skewY(-12deg);
transform: skewY(-12deg);
```

e para a div 'filha', desfaça o transform, para 'corrigir' o conteúdo:

```
-ms-transform: skewY(12deg);
-webkit-transform: skewY(12deg);
transform: skewY(12deg);
```

confira o snippet:

```css
.skew{
 margin-top:100px;
 background: black;
 display:inline-block;
 -ms-transform: skewY(-12deg);
 -webkit-transform: skewY(-12deg);
 transform: skewY(-12deg);
}
.skew>div {
 padding: 50px 100px;
 font: 30px/1 sans-serif;
 -ms-transform: skewY(12deg);
 -webkit-transform: skewY(12deg);
 transform: skewY(12deg);
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="skew">
 <div>Texto</div>
</div>
```

é só adaptar a sua necessidade

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um exemplo simples, usando `skew` apenas nos elementos `::after` e `::before`. Assim eu faço um X com os elemento, sendo que o conteúdo principal não precisa nem usar skew para corrigir. Se atente ao uso do `z-index` também pois um `::after` fica por cima da imagem e o `::before` por baixo

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.s {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url(http://unsplash.it/800/500);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -3;
}

.c {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -13%;
}
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 20px;
}
.c::before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(http://unsplash.it/800/500);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center bottom;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -4;
    transform: skewY(3deg);
}
.c::after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: aqua;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: skewY(-4deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="s">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Velit, nihil!
</div>
<div class="c">
    <div class="box">
        oi
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        oi
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        oi
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Exemplo usando as duas técnicas, invertendo valores de `skew` entre pai e filho, E outra tecnica usando `skew` só no `::after`

*Aqui no Snippet do Stackoverflow ele não vai funcionar bem, mas depois pode testar no seu projeto.*

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.s {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    transform: skewY(5deg);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: -120px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tor {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: skewY(-5deg);
    background-image: url(http://unsplash.it/800/500);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 100px;
}
.c {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px;
    height: 300px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    top: -50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.c::after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: navy;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform: skewY(-5deg);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
.box {
    background-color: aliceblue;
    width: 120px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="s">
    <div class="tor">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="c">
    <div class="box">
        oi
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        oi
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        oi
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que tenha feito certo, só faltou esconder a parte que sobra

```css
#pai {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#filho {
  background-color: skyblue;
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  margin: 50px -15%;
}
#texto {
  margin-left: 15%;
  transform: rotate(5deg);
  line-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pai">
  <div id="filho">
    <div id="texto">um texto qualquer de teste centraalizado verticalmente</div>
    </div>
</div>
```